# How come the config files in my ftplugin, indent, syntax folder don't work?

Tags: vim

I want to have 2 space indents for my .jade files when I edit them in vim. I downloaded config files for .jade processing in vim, but they do not seem to work. All of the folders are located in /home/name/.vim and each folder has jade.vim config files. They do not work though. Do I need to change the main .vimrc in /home/name?

Edit:

```
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.html setlocal ft=html
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.js setlocal ft=js
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.jade setlocal ft=jade
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.css setlocal ft=css
autocmd FileType html :setlocal sw=2 ts=2 sts=2
autocmd FileType js :setlocal sw=2 ts=2 sts=2
autocmd FileType jade :setlocal sw=2 ts=2 sts=2
autocmd FileType css :setlocal sw=2 ts=2 sts=2
```

When I use the above, I get the two spaces for a tab for .js files. But, then there is no syntax highlighting (I haven't tried the .html and .css files, but I assume the same would happen). I just want to override the tab spaces for these files but nothing else.
The jade file works well, though. Now, the jade file has syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I had to guess, I'd say your `.jade` files are not being detected properly and thus not having the `jade` filetype set.  Try adding the following in your `.vimrc` before the other autocmds above.

```
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.jade setlocal ft=jade
```

You can also confirm my theory by opening up a `.jade` file and running `:echo &ft`.  If whatever output you get is not `jade` then my theory is correct.

Comment: Oh cool, it works! I guess to make it work for css, html, and js, I just substitute the jade with the corresponding filetype. But, is there anyway where I can do it on the same line? Can I delimit the different filetypes with commas?

Comment: If it's not working for any filetypes then it sounds like you need 'filetype plugin on' in your .vimrc.